# Delay execution of crontab until @reboot was executed

Tags: cron

Every time I start my raspberry pi, I want to update and upgrade it.
No other cronjob should be run before this is finished.
My crontab looks like this now

```
@reboot sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
*/9 * * * * (python script1.py) &
*/4 * * * * (python script2.py) &
```

How do I make script1 and script2 wait?